# Remmina not launching 16.04

Tags: 16.04, remmina

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. When I try to launch Remmina Remote desktop nothing happens. When I try from the terminal window I get the following:

```
Remmina plugin VNC (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin VNCI (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin RDP (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPF (type=File) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPS (type=Preference) registered.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it hasn't helped. Can someone either please help, or perhaps recommend another remote desktop that I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Until you fix it you can use `vinagre`.

Comment: I found a solution: instead of installing it through the Software Centre, or by sudo apt-get install remmina, I found this on the github.com website:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp libfreerdp-plugins-standard

Problem solved! Thanks to those who helped.

Comment: I am using  1.1.2-3ubuntu1 (from the default repo) on 16.04 and it is starting without issues.

Comment: The ppa offers 1.2.0 - compared to 1.1.2. So it seems like your issue is fixed with the update, while the default version seems to work for others in the same distro.

Answer (score 7):

From @stroudmw's comments the following commands fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp libfreerdp-plugins-standard
```

Answer (score 0):

A remote desktop client that I use is [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/).

You can install it through apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

This is a commandline remote desktopclient that works like this:

```
rdesktop -u username -p "password" -d domain -0 IP -g size
```

**NOTE**: the quotes around the password are not always necessary but should be used when your password contains special characters like &.

I don't know if you're familiar with the `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory? It allows you to make aliases so you can run something from commandline.

Mine is filled like this:

```
alias nameofyouralias='rdesktop -u username -p "password" -d domain -0 IP -g 1024x768'
```

To reload your changes in the .bash_aliases file, you need to run `source ~/.bashrc` When you run `nameofyouralias` in the commandline, it will open the remote desktop session

Comment: Not sure if replacing software x with y is a real solution for this particular problem. It is a valid comment for sure ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that myself. The last sentence (or perhaps recommend another remote desktop that I can use?) made me place this as an answer instead of a comment. if that wasn't there, then I would've put it as a comment

Comment: Well, some people like to stick to their distributions official packages.